# java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java

I am having trouble with this code:

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Shapes extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    doDrawing();
}

private static void doDrawing() {
    Graphics2D g = null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
     g2d.drawLine(20, 20, 100, 100);
}

}
```

But when i run it i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at shapes.Shapes.doDrawing(Shapes.java:17)
at shapes.Shapes.main(Shapes.java:10)
```

How shall i fix this problem?

Comment: `Graphics2D g = null;` [see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a `null` element:

```
Graphics2D g = null;
```

And then you're trying to do something like this:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) null;
```

That's why you're getting `NullPointerException`.

I'm not really into [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class, but, based on this [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/examples/WeatherWizard.java) from docs, I made this code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Shapes extends JApplet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JApplet app = new Shapes();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.init();
        app.start();
        f.add("Center", app);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    Shapes() {
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawLine(20, 20, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

It draws the line you provided on your code.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You set `g` to `null`:

```
Graphics2D g = null;
```

and then cast this null and assign to `g2d`

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
```

and then call a method of a `null` object instance.